# Making a Class and content of it inBack4App

Tags: android

I am new to programming and i am a student trying to make a program that saves username able to log in, and saves user inputs such as moneys etc. I have downloaded the template (https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/login-android-tutorial) and it work well. I have already made a Class inside the Parse Dashboard and able to login and do registers thanks to the layout. But I tried to import the class that i made in back4app but i don't know how I tried using "import com.parse.ParseClass" and It won't work for some reason. Can someone please tell me what do I need to do to make a object inside the class in back4app? and use it in the android studio.

**EDIT** also somebody told me that I should open this in the Android SDK. But isn't that like a plugin to the gradle? If it is then I already have it in my gradle

**EDIT** I tried this code that I created but it doesn't send any data to back4app or whatsoever. after the button is pressed that's it it doesn't record any data (I think)

package com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample.Class;

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.example.back4app.userregistrationexample.R;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText balanceView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
            .applicationId(getString(R.string.back4app_app_id))
            .clientKey(getString(R.string.back4app_client_key))
            .server(getString(R.string.back4app_server_url))
            .build()
    );
    balanceView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_balance);
    final String currency = new String();

    final Button addbalance = findViewById(R.id.btn_addbalance);
    addbalance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ParseObject balance = new ParseObject(currency);
            balance.setObjectId(balanceView.getText().toString());
            balance.saveInBackground();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Add your code which have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you change your code to the below:

```
ParseObject balance = new ParseObject("nameOfYourClassHere");
balance.setObjectId(balanceView.getText().toString());
balance.saveInBackground();
```

Also, you can take a look at the official parse documentation:

https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/

Then, I'll recommend you take a look at the Back4App guide below to learn how to CRUD objects:

https://www.back4app.com/docs/android/parse-objects/crud